# Array to variable

Tags: c, arrays, type-conversion

I have a C code that I'm analizing and there is something like this:

```
variable = (unsigned long)rx;
```

If `rx` is an array of hex numbers and variable is of `unsigned long`, what will variable hold? The first element in `unsigned long` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that arrays decays to pointers. So what will happen is that the cast will convert the pointer (i.e. memory address) to an `unsigned long` and assign that to `variable`.

Answer (score 1):

Since [arrays decay to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying#) anytime you use an array's name, and do not deference it, you're going to get an address.

thus:

```
variable = (unsigned long)rx;
```

Will assign `rx[]`'s address to `variable` as an unsigned long value. Whereas this:

```
variable = (unsigned long)*rx;
```

or this:

```
variable = (unsigned long)rx[0];
```

will give you the value of the first element of `rx[]` (note that the syntax `rx[0]` is basically saying take the base address of `rx` + a `0` offset, dereference it and return the result)